# WKHTML - CFC wrapper for wkhtmltopdf from AbramAdams

Tags: coldfusion, wkhtmltopdf

I have been trying to use the CFC wrapper for wkhtmltopdf from AbramAdams with no luck in getting it to do anything. I think it may be a path issue but not sure. I am trying the example given.

```
<cfscript>
    wkhtmltopdf = new menueditortestsite.menueditor.com.wkhtml.pdf();
    results = wkhtmltopdf.create(
            url = 'https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Home', // uncomment to test with url
            options = {
                "viewport-size":"1200x1080" // default
                ,"image-quality":100
                ,"margin-bottom": 25
                ,"margin-left": "5mm"
                ,"margin-right": "5mm"
                ,"margin-top": 45
                ,"orientation": "portrait" //default
                ,"encoding": "utf-8"
                ,"header-html": "http://www.sydneytripslipfallcompensation.com/images/header.jpg"
                ,"footer-html": "<footer style='text-align:center;'>This, my friend, is a cool footer.</footer>"
            },
            writeToFile = false, // true will write the file and return a struct containing the path (and other info)
            destination = "#expandPath('.')#\pdf\test.pdf"
    );
    // if you set writeToFile to true, uncomment the below and comment out the cfheader/cfcontent block below

    /*
  writeDump(results);
    text = wkhtmltopdf.getText( results.file );
    pagedText = wkhtmltopdf.getText( results.file );
    writeDump({
        "text":text,
        "pagedText":pagedText
    });*/

</cfscript>

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=test.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#expandPath('.')#test.pdf">
```

I have wkhtmltopdf installed on windows and I have added this to the system path as `C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\` .
I have tested wkhtmltopdf to make sure it is working with success but using the CFC wrapper nothing happens. 
I have tried the following with no success. Can someone help me figure out if it is my path code or something else wrong with the developers code?

```
wkhtmltopdf = new menueditortestsite.menueditor.com.wkhtml.pdf();
wkhtmltopdf = new menueditortestsite.menueditor.com.wkhtml.pdf('C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe');
wkhtmltopdf = new menueditortestsite.menueditor.com.wkhtml.pdf('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf');
wkhtmltopdf = new menueditortestsite.menueditor.com.wkhtml.pdf(expandPath('../com/wkhtml/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe'));
```

This is the code I ran with no errors reported.

```
wkhtmltopdf = new menueditortestsite.menueditor.com.wkhtml.pdf();   
results = wkhtmltopdf.create(
        url = 'https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Home', // uncomment to test with url
        options = {
            "viewport-size":"1200x1080" // default
            ,"image-quality":100
            ,"margin-bottom": 25
            ,"margin-left": "5mm"
            ,"margin-right": "5mm"
            ,"margin-top": 45
            ,"orientation": "portrait" //default
            ,"encoding": "utf-8"
            ,"header-html": "http://www.sydneytripslipfallcompensation.com/images/header.jpg"
            ,"footer-html": "<footer style='text-align:center;'>This, my friend, is a cool footer.</footer>"
        },
        writeToFile = true, // true will write the file and return a struct containing the path (and other info)
        destination = "#expandPath('.')#\pdf\test.pdf"
);

writeDump(results);abort;
text = wkhtmltopdf.getText( results.file );
pagedText = wkhtmltopdf.getText( results.file );
writeDump({
    "text":text,
    "pagedText":pagedText
});
```

Comment: You didn't include the URL to the CFC library you are using.  It's https://github.com/abramadams/wkhtml

I was getting some errors and realized that EXE arguments may need to be in a specific order, so I wrote a CF8-2016 Custom Tag. It uses parameters that are similar to CFDocument and automatically converts inches to mm.
https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/74e556e7d4f1a715a41d

Comment: Sorry about that url. I appreciate the CT but I am wanting to pass raw html via form to wkhtmltopdf to create a pdf as apposed to a url. Will your CT handle this?

Comment: WKHTMLTOPDF can't do that as far as I know... the command line only accepts three (3) URLs: body, header & footer.  You have use ColdFusion to save the HTML to a local temp file first and then pass the file's URL to the WKHTMLTOPDF executable.

Comment: So you don't get the `writeDump`?  Maybe try `writeDump(results);abort;`?  Also, the wrapper will accept a url or raw html.

Comment: WKHTMLTOPDF can do this because I am currently using a cf wrapper from here https://github.com/LoicMahieu/cf-wkhtmltopdf and it works fine by passing in form data. I thought I would try another wrapper alternative to see how it's results were. However, I can not seem to get their example to work. This resulted in my question above.

Comment: @SGekko, I'm the author of the wkhtml wrapper (https://github.com/abramadams/wkhtml).  If you can elaborate on "nothing happens" I may be able to help.  Did you try my suggestions?  Any output?

Comment: Hello Abram, I thought I would give your wrapper a go so I setup your example just to see how well it worked for my project  but when I run your example code no PDF is produced.  WKHTMLTOPDF is setup correctly on my server and is in the system path. This has been tested and works fine. I get no errors in the console when I run the code above. I dont have much more to offer. If you could help it would be great.

Comment: set `writeToFile = true` in the `create()` call then after call `writeDump(results);abort;` to see if it reports any errors.

Comment: I have posted the code I just ran above with no errors reported.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129491/discussion-between-abram-and-sgekko).